# Appdynamics - Experience journey map - drop-off rate

Tags: appdynamics

We are using AppDynamics to monitor an iOS app. In Experience Journey map in AppDynamics what does the "drop-off rate" mean?
[drop-off rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8z6L.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Drop-off rate is the percentage of user sessions which reach the specific page and then end their session (they do not reach any further pages as part of the session and therefore "drop-off" the map).

This can be seen in the example (image) in the [documentation](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Experience+Journey+Map)